# Queryselector remove redundant comma separated list of items

Tags: javascript, html, input

Is there a grouping feature in the querySelector? Currently I have to list out all of the input types I want to match which results in redundant strings like this:

```
form.querySelectorAll('input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email], input[type=number]')
```

Is there a way to remove the redundancy to maybe look something like this:

```
form.querySelectorAll('input[type={text,password,email,number}]')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as CSS selectors go, there’s only [`:matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:matches). It doesn’t make much of an improvement and doesn’t work unprefixed in any browser except for Safari.

```
form.querySelectorAll(
    'input:matches([type=text], [type=password], [type=email], [type=number])')
```

You can build the string with JavaScript, though:

```
form.querySelectorAll(
    'text,password,email,number'.replace(/\w+/g, 'input[type=$&]'))
```

Comment: There’s not really a need to “abuse” the default `toString` behavior. Just use `.join(",")` at the end.

Comment: @Xufox: It’s shorter

Comment: @Ry- But it is ugly, not explicit. Not readable at all until someone knows the default thing.

Comment: I don’t think it’s readable to do it at all, with or without `.join`

Answer (score 6):

There's no built-in method that can do that, but it's easy to build your own function that can build a query string like that, allowing you to write more DRY code:

```js
const makeQuery = types => types.map(type => `input[type="${type}"]`).join(', ');
console.log(makeQuery(['text', 'password', 'email', 'number']))
```